# Issue with Recycler View Sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-recyclerview

I am displaying data from `Sqlite` database in `RecyclerView` with which there is `AddToCart` button. On clicking this button, data of that item gets store in `sqlite` database. `Recyclerview` loads data when its visible. The issue is that when `recycelerview` reloads data its giving me strange behavior. The items which are not in the cart are showing its actually in the cart. There is no problem in the `sqlite` database but in the `recyclerview`. When there are less items in the list and there is no need to reload data in `recyclerview` then it don't show this kind of behavior. It only shows this behavior when there is need to reload `recyclerview` data on scrolling i.e loading more data. `onBindViewHolder` is responsible because it reloads data every time its visible on screen. This code is working fine on less data when there is no need for `recyclerview` to reload data.

```
final String image = list.get(position).getImage();
    final String description = list.get(position).getDescriptionn();
    final String quantity = list.get(position).getQuantity();
    final String price = list.get(position).getPricee();
    final String measuring_unit = list.get(position).getMeasuring_unit();
    String s = price + "Rs";
    viewHolder.pricee.setText(s);
    viewHolder.product_name.setText(name);
    String quantityAndMeasuringunit = quantity+" "+measuring_unit;
    viewHolder.measuring_unit.setText(quantityAndMeasuringunit);
    Picasso.get()
            .load(image)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.dairy1)
            .error(R.drawable.dairy2)
            .into(viewHolder.sriv);


    Cursor c = dh.getCartDetailItemForUpdatingAddToCartButtonBySub_cat_name(id);  //it checks if MilkAdapter2 items are present in cart table
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String product_id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cart_detail_id"));
            Log.e(TAG, "getCartDetailItemForUpdatingAddToCartButtonBySub_cat_name "+product_id);
            if (id.equals(product_id)) {  // if present just update the AddToCart status
                String product_quantity = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("AddToCartQuantity"));
                Log.e(TAG, "getCartDetailItemForUpdatingAddToCartButtonBySub_cat_name "+product_quantity);
                Log.e(TAG, "ViewHolder " + " " + product_id);
                //Log.e(TAG, "inside for loop "+name + " " + quantity);

                viewHolder.textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.digit.setText(product_quantity + "");
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
        c.close();
    }

    viewHolder.sriv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, Item_detail.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra("id",list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getItem_id());
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

ViewHolder Class

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                String id = list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getItem_id();
                String image = list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getImage();
                String price = list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPricee();
                String description = list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getDescriptionn();
                String quantity = list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getQuantity();
                String name = list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getName();
                String measuring_unit = list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getMeasuring_unit();
                String sub_cat_name = list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getSub_cat_name();

                Log.e(TAG, name);
                Log.e(TAG, sub_cat_name);
                InsertInCart.InsertInCartDatabase(context, Constant.vegetable_category, id, name, image, price, description, quantity, measuring_unit, sub_cat_name);
            }
        });
```

I think its more like deadlock problem because it enters in if condition on other items also. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.
I clicked only on `AddToCart` button of first item.

[image]

When I scrolled to end and back to top second item `addtocart` got triggered which I haven't clicked.

[image]
On scrolling to end second last `addtocart` button got triggered.

[image]

Comment: I think you have messed with saving item state. Please post your `Adapter` code

Comment: Images looks weird, Goat head :/

Comment: @Abu Yousaf @ Khemraj just  curious have you done this kind of project before

Comment: @AbuYousuf Please have a look at my code. I have updated it.

Comment: @Khemraj Please have a look at my code. I have updated it.

Comment: this is a part of your code. where this code belong ? is it `onBindViewHolder` method code?

Comment: @AbuYousuf is there any way to implement addtocart.

Comment: Yes. @AbuYousuf

Comment: @AbuYousuf just like I save Add to cart items in android app and then show it.

Comment: Where is your `addtoCart` clickListener ?

Comment: @AbuYousuf first it was in onBindViewHolder. To check whether it has something to do with this error I have set it in ViewHolder class. Error remain persistent.

Comment: @AbuYousuf Sir I have updated code Have A look.

Comment: @AbuYousuf By any chance, can RecyclerView show this strange kind of behaviour? Bcs its been days I am searching error with no luck.